# What is the average brewing time for craft beer?

Tags: brewing

Given craft beers, which are typically brewed without many preservatives, what is the average duration a beer must sit inside a barrel before it is ready for serving?

If different types of beer require different brewing times, can you provide a list?

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the beer really. Lagers are typically brewed longer than ales. Of the few brews I've made so far, I usually let them ferment for 2 weeks in the fermenter, then I bottle them and wait another 2 weeks.